# help with simplify the following expression as much as you can

Tags: linear-algebra

$$ Ha = A (1 - \sum\limits_1^W(Z_n))^2 + A(\sum\limits_1^W(nZ_n) - \sum\limits_1^N(W_iX_i))^2 $$

i have the following expression, and it's been a while since my Bachelor’s degree, so i forget most of the stuff...

basically, i want to be able to extract linear terms and quadratic terms from the simplifaication of the expression; and then, using some Vectorisation and matrix of the binary variables (Z and X) to get to this form:
and by Regrouping the terms in the quadratic form to get to:
$$
\min_{\bf z\in \{0,1\}^{n(n+1)}} \bf z^T {\bf Q} \bf z + {\bf g}^T \bf z + c,
$$

where the  is the × matrix
 and g  are -dimensional vectors,
and c is a constant